# Integrate $\int\frac{x \sec^2 x \times e^{\sec(x^2)}\:dx}{\cos^2(x^2)}$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

Integrate $$I=\int\frac{x \sec^2 x \cdot e^{\sec(x^2)}\:dx}{\cos^2(x^2)}$$

I used the substitution $x^2=t$ we get

$$I=\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{e^{\sec t} \cdot \sec^2(\sqrt{t}) \:dt}{\cos^2 t}$$

Any clue now?

Comment: Are you sure the top is not $\sec^2x^2$?

Comment: Are you sure that the question should read as $\sec^2 x$ instead of $\sec^2 x^2$? Your integral can be computed in the latter case if you make one step further and substitute $u=\sec t$